# How to Stop the Spring Batch Job Execution Immediately or forcefully?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch, spring-batch-job-monitoring

I have a spring batch job and it has 3 steps, the 3rd step has some tasklet as below. Now when we try to stop the job using,

```
jobOperator.stop(id);
```

it sends the STOP signal when STEP 3 is in progress and interrupts only when all the tasklet in the STEP 3 is completed. Let's say it has 10 tasks, although we sent the stop signal when it was STEP 3 and Task 1 in progress - it does not stop there. It finishes all the 10 tasks and then marks this STEP 3 status as COMPLETED. Is there any way we can stop step 3 while processing the first task? I did see the spring batch documentation and did not find much. Below is the sample code.

Job:

```
   @Bean(JobConstants.CONTENT_UPGRADE_JOB)
    public Job upgradeContentJob() {
        Tasklet tasklet = context.getBean("incremental_deploy_tasklet", Tasklet.class);
        SimpleJobBuilder jobBuilder = jobBuilderFactory.get(JobConstants.CONTENT_UPGRADE_JOB)
                .listener(upgradeJobResultListener())
                .start(initContent())
                .next(stepBuilderFactory.get("create_snapshot_tasklet").tasklet(createSnapshotTasklet()).build())
                .next(stepBuilderFactory.get("incremental_deploy_tasklet").tasklet(tasklet).build());

        return jobBuilder.build();
    }
```

Tasks:

```
packCompositionMap.put(incremental_content_deploy, Arrays.asList(
            create_security_actions ,slice_content, upgrade_appmodule, 
  application_refresh,
            install_reset_roles_bar, restore_reset_roles_bar,
            populate_roles, add_roles,
            replay_security_actions,
            create_adw_connection,
            apply_system_extensions,
            replay_system_steps,
            assign_service_admin
    ));
```

Here STOP signal for the id is sent when "incremental_deploy_tasklet" is just initiated and "create_security_actions" task is picked from the array list but the problem is it does not stops but completes all the item task in the array and then marks the status for this "incremental_deploy_tasklet"  step as STOPPED and then overall status for this job is also marked as STOPPED.

What I am looking for is help on to STOP and interrupt at this "create_security_actions" task itself.  Any help or input is appreciated, Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading multiple docs and trying it-  found that we cannot terminate the thread immediately. The control should come back to the framework.
The shutdown is not immediate, since there is no way to force an immediate shutdown, especially if the execution is currently in developer code that the framework has no control over, such as a business service. However, as soon as control is returned back to the framework, it will set the status of the current StepExecution to BatchStatus.STOPPED, save it, then do the same for the JobExecution before finishing.

Thank you.